# Does System.out.println() create a String If we concatenate?

Tags: java, string

I was asked this question today in an interview.
Can someone explain me the right answer ?

Here is the code.

```
String s1= "hellow";
String s2= "Hellow again";

System.out.println(s1+s2);
```

How many strings are created in the above code ?
I think it will be 3.Any suggestions?

Comment: Questionable. You could in fact argue that the above code would only *create* one string due to string interning. There definitely will be a max of 3 at runtime though.

Comment: What would suggest that it WOULDN'T be 3 (depending, as @user3580294 suggests, what you mean by "create")?

Comment: The interviewer just asked me that how many strings will be created in the above code ? Can You me the Answer please ?

Comment: If it's *just this code on it's own* then yes, it's 3. If this code is a subset of more code, then it's possible that `s1` and `s2` already exist elsewhere, meaning when you declare them, they're just pulled from the heap.

Comment: `println()` is irrelevant to this scenario. Any function call would have the strings behave the same way.

Comment: Three String objects are created. It first creates a String object for "hellow", because it is not currently in the String pool. The same happens for "Hellow again". The + operator creates a new String object that is a concatenation of "hello" and "Hellow again".

Comment: @christopher Wouldn't that depend on what is meant by "create"? Technically the `String`s that `s1` and `s2` are assigned to already exist in the constant pool when the program starts because they are compile-time constants... So the code itself doesn't "create" the `String`s directly

Comment: Be careful. Were `s1` and `s2` declared `final` in the interview’s question? That makes a difference, as in case of `final` variables only *one* `String` is created (unless debugging information for unused variables is requested).

Comment: @Holger they were not final . But why declaring them final will create only 1 string. I didn't understood ? Can You please Explain a bit more.Thanks

Comment: @farhangdon: if `s1` and `s2` are `final` and immediately assigned, the compiler treats them as *compile-time constants*. And concatenation of two compile-time constants results in another compile-time constant which the compiler will insert right into the `print` call. Since `s1` and `s2` are unused (at runtime) then, it depends on the debug settings, whether the `String`s for `s1` and `s2` are retained in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literals `"hellow"` and `"Hellow again"` are in the string pool.

Now when we concatenate with `s1 + s2`, what really happens is the following:

```
new StringBuilder(s1).append(s2).toString()
```

which itself creates a new `String` ([see for yourself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.toString%28%29)). So it depends what you mean by "create"; if you're asking how many `String` objects exist at the very end of the snippet, then the answer is 3. But note that the string produced by `s1+s2` is not retained and is therefore eligible to be garbage collected after it is printed.

Comment: @christopher The answer comes down to what you mean by "create". If you mean how many string objects exist by the end of the program, then the answer is 3.

Comment: So According to You there will be 3 strings created ?

Comment: @arshajii I understand your point, but if this is a point of contention then please make sure that you include this information in your answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that the result depends on the compiler.  For the given code snippet, it is perfectly legal for the compiler to treat `s1` and `s2` as effectively final, and replace the concatenation operation with a loading of the constant string `"hellowHellow again"`.  Note that this is what would happen with `javac` if you were to declare `s1` and `s2` as `final`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes, that's true if the two were declared `final`. I'm not sure if the compiler is allowed to treat the strings as effectively final and perform the same optimization, however.

Comment: @arshajii I do not know of anything in the language spec that would disallow such an optimization.  The compiler should be free to perform the optimization because the result is provably correct.  The implementation details change from time to time, and indeed appear to have changed subtly for Java 8 (`new StringBuilder.append(s1).append(s2).toString()`, as opposed passing `s1` in the constructor).

Comment: @MikeStrobel For whatever reason, on my machine it took `final` for the compiler to optimize. Not really sure why, as this seems to be simple enough to prove that `s1` and `s2` are effectively `final`...

Comment: @user3580294 No version of `javac` that I am aware of performs the optimization above without an explicit `final` modifier on both variables.  But I'm not aware of any restrictions that would prevent future versions from applying the same optimization to "effectively final" variables, nor do I know whether eclipse or other compilers perform such an optimization.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I'm curious why, as `javac` already has the capability to determine whether a field is "effectively final" to deal with anonymous classes/lambdas and such...

Comment: @user3580294 You'd have to open up the JDK's `langtools` and step through `javac` to see why.  I suspect the variables *are* being flagged as [`EFFECTIVELY_FINAL`](http://code.google.com/p/jsr308-langtools/source/browse/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Flags.java?spec=svn7fcf0d8ebac08a5cf353267db0e2f664953be6e1&r=7fcf0d8ebac08a5cf353267db0e2f664953be6e1#232), but the optimization is probably coded to require a true `FINAL` flag.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That sounds like a good way to burn a few hours. Ended up going a lot deeper into the internals of Java than I expected...

Answer (score 2):

This answer is essentially an extension of arshajii's answer

The answer all depends on what your interviewer(s) meant by "create", and technically also depends on what other code is present.

If you disassemble the bytecode generated by just that snippet, you get this:

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: ldc           #2                  // String hellow
   2: astore_1      
   3: ldc           #3                  // String Hellow again
   5: astore_2      
   6: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   9: new           #5                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  12: dup           
  13: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  16: aload_1       
  17: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  20: aload_2       
  21: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  24: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  27: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  30: return
```

Because `"hellow"` and `"Hellow again"` are string literals in the source code, they get placed into the constant pool at compile time, and so are present at program startup. As you can see, the strings `"hellow"` and `"Hellow again"` are simply loaded (`ldc == load constant`). They are not *created* by the above code snippet. The only `String` that's created is the one from the `StringBuilder`.

Now, if you declare the fields `final`, you get this:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3: ldc           #3                  // String hellowHellow again
   5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   8: return
```

Based on this, you can also argue that *no* `String` objects are created by the above code snippet, as the compiler can optimize this statement. This is probably not the answer that the interviewers were looking for, since it depends on `final` being present.

Comment: Indeed, the question is worded somewhat ambiguously.  One could interpret the question as asking how many strings need to be allocated to satisfy execution of the snippet in question at least once.  In that case, though, one may also need to include the 20-odd other strings that would be loaded into memory when reading the class's constant pool.  If you limit the scope to only those strings allocated during execution of the method body, there is just one string allocated.  I think that is the more reasonable interpretation, and you touched on the `final` aspect, so +1 to you.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Just curious, what would those other strings be?

Comment: type and method descriptors, among other things.  Run `javap -v` and look at the contents of the constant pool.  Presumably those will be loaded during parsing of the classfile, even if they are discarded shortly thereafter.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Interesting... Only knew about the `-c` option previously. Oddly enough, I only see 2 `String` objects... But there's a whole ton of `Utf8` objects whose purpose I'm not sure about...

Comment: all text-based values in constant pool are ultimately stored as `Utf8StringConstant` entries; they are simply strings.  The `StringConstant` entries referencing them indicate that those constants are referenced by `ldc[_w]` opcode(s) somewhere in the classfile.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Ah, that makes sense. Where might I learn more about this kind of thing? I only know a little about the deeper workings of Java/the JVM, and this is making me want to learn more.

Comment: The [JVM Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) contains everything you (n)ever wanted to know about the classfile format.  A great way to learn more is to pick an open source [decompiler](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon) or disassembler and explore how it parses class files.

Comment: @MikeStrobel All right, guess I know how I'm spending my summer. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a summer well spent :).  I'm the author of the decompiler I linked above, so I've spent my fair share of time poking around bytecode.  Feel free to get in contact with me if you have questions.  The author of the Krakatau decompiler is also active on StackOverflow, and he knows the stuff inside and out (his decompiler even includes a verifier).

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yep, guessed so when I saw the username in the URL. I've only really begun getting into Java this past semester, and this seems like a good way to really expand my knowledge. Thanks for your offer! Can't say if I'm going to take you up on it any time soon, but don't be surprised if you see a .edu email show up in your inbox at some point.

Comment: The [class file format can be found in the Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) rather than the Java Language Specification. But if you want to go deeply into the matter, both are worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable so s1+s2 creates a new String instance. If you want to avoid this you should use a StringBuffer.

Comment: Relevant, but doesn't answer the question in it's totality. Please link this back to the original question and explain why it's important.

Comment: You'll still have to create a `String` eventually to print

Answer (score 0):

The [operator hierarchy](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php) in Java states, that String concatenation is being evaluated before a method call. Therefore the expression in brackets first creates a new String and is then being written to the standard output.

My answer: 3

Answer (score 0):

The answer is implementation dependent, and it also depends on the context ... and what you mean by creation.

The *execution* of those lines of code creates one `String` object for the concatenation, and possibly others within the `println` call<sup>1</sup>.  These creations would happen each time your application executes those lines.

At least a further two String objects will be created when the code is loaded and String objects are created for the String literals.  However, that is a once off ...

---

<sup>1 - In some class libraries, `println(s)` is implemented as `print(s + newline)`.  Hence the `println` call *may* create another `String` object.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

And the right answer for an interview question is probably not "`3`" but some (but not necessarily all) of the discussion above.  They'd definitely want you to know that `+` creates a string; probably want some awareness that the constants `s1` and `s2` are created/exist as compile-time constants; and may be suitably impressed if you knew about the effect of adding `final`.  Such questions are often not about getting the right answer, but thinking about them in the right way.

Answer (score -1):

3 is the answer.

But use a StringBuilder (as StringBuffer is useless thread safe version of the StringBuilder).

You should use the StringBuilder.append method, instead of the + operator.

Comment: No, he shouldn't. s1 + s2 is compiled to byte-code using a StringBuilder, and StringBuilder is actually faster than StringBuffer, which is synchronized for no good reason.

Comment: And this isn't his code. This is code he was given in a job interview.